# How to Register the RowLeave event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form in VSTO addin.  I want to register the FormX_RowLeave() method.  I register functions like this since I am using visual designer.

```
this.clientsProjectHistoryDataGridView.CellLeave += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.clientsProjectHistoryDataGridView_CellLeave);
```

But I don't know how to do this with RowLeave.  I can't find any examples or find it in the docs.  I found the method in the docs but not how to register the event handler.  I've tried using visual studio's features to display the available methods or objects  to find a DataGridViewXXXEventHandler that applies to RowLeave, but I cannot find one.  Not in the docs or anywhere else I've looked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't know how to do this with RowLeave. Any suggestions? I can't find any examples or find it in the docs. I found the method in the docs but not how to register the event handler

`DataGridView` has a `RowLeave` event property that you can subscribe to by double-clicking it in the designer (ensure you are on the **Events** page by clicking the little *lightning bolt* icon):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle an event when it fires, you need to register an event handler.  An event handler is a method that matches the signature the event expects (aka a delegate).  According to [the docs for `DataGridView.RowLeave`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx), the event's expects a method that is a [`DataGridViewCellEventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate, which has
a method signature that looks like this:

```
void DataGridViewCellEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e
)
```

All you have to do is write a method that matches that signature (by convention, it's named something like `clientsProjectHistoryDataGridView_RowLeave`).  First, setup the event handling method in your code.  It might look like

```
private void DataGridViewCellEventHandler(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
{
    //do stuff, casting the sender if needed
}
```

Then just register your `DataGridView`'s event, usually in the constructor or `Form_Load` event.

```
this.clientsProjectHistoryDataGridView.RowLeave += DataGridViewCellEventHandler;
```

Comment: Thanks it works, oddly when I add it in properties, it create sthe function even though I already created it, and  if I delete the function it created and use the other one I made before with the same name, it throws an error.  Odd, but i t's working anyway

Comment: Yep, visual studio intellisense can sometimes make weird suggestions.  Ultimately, as long as the compiler sees that the method you registered (by name) has a signature that matches the form it expects, everything will run.  Before the designers got so good, you had to manually register events this way.

Comment: Yes I recall, I just couldn't get it to work for some reason without going through properties where it wasn't in the dropdown so I entered the method name manually, then letting it make the method and then deleting my old ones (of same name) and adding my code the new ones

Answer (score 0):

```
this.clientsProjectHistoryDataGridView.RowLeave += this.clientsProjectHistoryDataGridView_RowLeave;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.